# Branch.io - Save template for events in sources table

Tags: analytics, branch.io

Currently, when opening the Branch Dashboard -> Sources, the same default events are always listed in the analytics table and no filter is set.

Very often you want to compare the same setup from one week to another or something alike. In Adjust you can save templates of tables with filters, event sets, time frames, etc. You can easily navigate through the custom sets.

Branch is my favorite campaign tracking platform but the analysis currently is a pain. Is there anyway I haven't found yet to save templates for tables in Branch?

Comment: Amruta from Branch here. Thank you so much for your feedback. Branch strives to provide a smooth experience for both you and your users. Unfortunately, we currently do not have the feature to save templates on the dashboard, but I have informed our engineering team about this feature request and they are looking into it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of now, Branch does not have an option to save an analytics/reporting template. It is a known feature request, that we are planning to release. Thank you for your input!

Comment: Is this feature expected to be implemented somewhen in the near future?